# " Invalid field in source data: 0 " exception when using

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am serializeing many object and write it to a stream then deserializing these objects from the stream using Protobuf.net.

the object type is determined at runtime, so I have to use the NonGeneric method "TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix".

I keep getting the "Invalid field in source data: 0" exception. But when I use the generic method "DeserializeWithLengthPrefix()" it works fine.

And very strangely, I get " Invalid field in source data: 0 " at first, but when I changed the array lenth I start to get "System.InvalidOperationException"! The first exception only occurs when the lenth is 5 or 9. I have tried using a class instead of int[], but the result is the same.

below is the test code,
Thank you very much for your help.

```
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream inputStream;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //an int array as the object to serialize
            var data = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

            Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(outputStream, data, PrefixStyle.Base128);
        }

        var dataBytes = outputStream.ToArray();
        inputStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);

        while (inputStream.Position != inputStream.Length)
        {
            object output;
            //not working, "System.InvalidOperationException" or "Invalid field in source data: 0" depend on the lenth of the array
            Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(inputStream, PrefixStyle.Base128, t => typeof(int[]), out output);
            //working! every time
            var output = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<int[]>(inputStream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            foreach (var num in (int[])output)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are slightly different scenarios, due to an optional argument. The `SerializeWithLengthPrefix` and `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` methods you are using have an optional argument that - if omitted - defaults to zero. This means you are serializing with a zero but **without** a field-number (a zero field-number  is never legal in protobuf). Some people need that. There is another overload that allows you to specify a field-number *as well as* a length prefix.

The overload of `TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix` that you are using is intended to be used in the second scenario - specifically, the version you are using with the delegate is intended to allow you to tell the serializer what type it should think about *based on the field-number* (in your case, `t => typeof(int[])` would return the same thing for each tag `t`). If you intend using that version to deserialize, you *must* include a field-number when serializing, for example:

```
Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(
    outputStream, data, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
```

and

```
var output = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<int[]>(
    inputStream, PrefixStyle.Base128, 1);
```

This should then *also* work correctly with the line:

```
Serializer.NonGeneric.TryDeserializeWithLengthPrefix(
    inputStream, PrefixStyle.Base128, t => typeof(int[]), out output);
```

(and you should find that `t` is `1`).

Alternatively, if you don't want field-numbers in the data, you could use `TryReadLengthPrefix(...)` to get a length, then create a `ProtoReader` to specify *that exact length*.

As a side note: you should usually avoid checking `.Length` vs `.Position` in a `Stream`, as `.Length` is often not available (and `.Position` is sometimes not supported either). You'll get away with it in things like `MemoryStream` and `FileStream`, though. It is better to just use `while` over the `Try...(...)` method, which returns `false` if it finds the end of the stream.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, you saved my day.     Could you give me a simple example on how to use the `ProtoReader`? It could save me a byte every time i serialize a object.

Comment: @wei IIRC there are overloads (particularly on the non-generic API) of deserialize that accept a reader; you just `new` a reader for the desired length (use RuntimeTypeModel.Default as the model, and null as the context) and pass it in...